# Asp Net Core - Error persisting Value Object

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to persist a value valuobject from address and I get the error below, I am using postgres and I already tried to map this class in several ways, I saw that some people had similar problems but I did not find the solution.
I only encounter this error when using ef core

System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity of type 'EmpresaModel' is sharing the table 'Empresa.Empresa' with entities of type 'EnderecoEmpresa', but there is no entity of this type with the same key value that has been marked as 'Added'. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.'

```
        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.EnderecoEmpresa, a =>
        {
            a.Property(p => p.Bairro).HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasColumnName("Bairro")
                .HasDefaultValue("");
            a.Property(p => p.CEP).HasMaxLength(10)
                .HasColumnName("CEP")
                .HasDefaultValue("");
            a.Property(p => p.Complemento).HasMaxLength(60)
                .HasColumnName("Complemento")
                .HasDefaultValue("");
            a.Property(p => p.IdMunicipio)
                .HasColumnName("MunicipioId");
            a.Property(p => p.IdUF)
                .HasColumnName("UfId");            
            a.Property(p => p.Logradouro)
                .HasColumnName("Logradouro").HasMaxLength(60)
                .HasDefaultValue("");
            a.Property(p => p.Numero)
                .HasColumnName("Numero").HasMaxLength(10)
                .HasDefaultValue("");
        });
```

Comment: Hi Rafael, I think that you may get better results and answers if you are able to refactor your question using English. I know that not everyone is a native English speaker, but it may help your question have a larger reach to the community.

Comment: This is an English language site. Please post in that language, or ask your question at [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead.

Comment: @EvanBechtol: You may find [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262015/62576) helpful.

Comment: i´m sorry... edited question